# Problem in importing python library in chaquopy android studio

Tags: python, android, android-studio, nltk, chaquopy

this the Gradle: app file code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.chaquo.python'
android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.speechtotext"
    sourceSets{
        main{
            python{
                srcDirs=["src/main/python"]
            }
        }
    }

    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
    python{

        buildPython "C:/Users/YASHWANTH REDDY/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/python.exe"}
    }
    python{
        pip{
            install "nltk"
        }
    }
    }
    buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
   }
   }
   }
   dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
   implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
   implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
   implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
   implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0'
   compile files('libs/opennlp-tools-1.6.0.jar')
   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
   }
```

this the Gradle:(python in android)

```
  buildscript {
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://chaquo.com/maven" }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
    classpath "com.chaquo.python:gradle:9.0.0"
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
  }
 allprojects {
 repositories {
    google()
    centre()
 }
 }
 task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I have linked all the plugins, as that mentioned in chaquopy official documentation, I am getting the following error.

```
enter code here

   A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:/Users/YASHWANTH''. Please set buildPython to your Python executable path. See https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html#buildpython.
```

I am not getting the above error when I removed the

```
     python{
        pip{
            install "nltk"
        }
    }
```

so please help me why I getting the above error when I try to install any python library,

Answer (score 0):

`buildPython` can't accept filenames containing spaces in this version of Chaquopy. This was [fixed in Chaquopy 9.1.0](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/changelog.html).

**For Chaquopy 9.0.0 and older:**

If you previously installed Python with default settings, you may have the `py` command available on your PATH, which Chaquopy will use automatically. Try just removing the `buildPython` line and see if it works.

If not, download Python from [python.org](https://www.python.org/) and install it with default settings. Then you should be able to remove the `buildPython` line.